# Adding effect to the bootstrap carousel slides

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I'm using the bootstrap carousel as in its website and there are 3 slides that each contains an image and a div of texts.
I want to manipulate it as on slide change, the texts animated from right to left.
I've included the code snippet and I'll appreciate your help.

```js
 var $carousel = $('#myCarousel');
 $carousel.bind('slide.bs.carousel', function(e) {
   $('#myCarousel .item .container div').animate({
     'top': '-50px',
     'opacity': '0.5'
       //  transition: 'all 0.5s all 0.4s ease-in-out',
   },500);
   $('#myCarousel .item.active .container div').animate({
     // transition: 'all 0.5s all 0.4s ease-in-out',
     'top': '0',
     'opacity': '1'
   },500);
 });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <style>
    .carousel-inner > .item > img,
    .carousel-inner > .item > a > img {
      width: 70%;
      margin: auto;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container">
    <br>
    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
      <!-- Indicators -->
      <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
      </ol>

      <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
      <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
        <div class="item active">
          <img src="http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/img_chania2.jpg" alt="Chania" width="460" height="345">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="carousel-caption" style="background-color:rgba(255,255,255,0.2)">
              <h1>H1</h1>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="item">
          <img src="http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/img_chania.jpg" alt="Chania" width="460" height="345">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="carousel-caption" style="background-color:rgba(255,255,255,0.2)">
              <h1>H1</h1>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="item">
          <img src="http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/img_flower.jpg" alt="Chania" width="460" height="345">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="carousel-caption" style="background-color:rgba(255,255,255,0.2)">
              <h1>H1</h1>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Left and right controls -->
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
  </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Your animations are likely not doing what you're hoping - they're causing the caption background to expand up to the top of the image. To my eyes, it works better with both of those animates taken out, after which, the caption text does slide in with the image from right to left, though it still might not be quite the animation you're looking for.

Comment: @SheldonGriffin yeap, but the problem is not the animations, the problem is that I can't perform animations on next slide, it is executed on the previous slide and not in next rotations

Comment: check this link, perhavs it help you to figure out how to add animations to text  https://www.sitepoint.com/bootstrap-carousel-with-css3-animations/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be that the issue is that you're attempting both of the animations in the slide.bs.carousel handler, so they are both being applied to the same element. If you break it up into the slide.bs.carousel (which happens before the slide) and slid.bs.carousel (which happens after the new slide) events, you'll have better control of the "pre"/"post" slide.

Check here for an example. I used slideUp instead of animate, but you should be able to replace with whatever animation you want. https://jsfiddle.net/sheldon_griffin/zz9nwng3/1/

```
$('#myCarousel').on('slide.bs.carousel', function(e) {
  $('.carousel-caption').hide();
}).on('slid.bs.carousel', function(e) {
  $('.active .carousel-caption').slideToggle('slow');
});
```

Comment: Thank you, it is exactly what I need